# VrVideoView is not importing after download google VR SDK. 360 3d video play on app

Tags: android, android-studio, virtual-reality, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

i am trying to make a android app in android studio in which users can watch 360 degree videos. i tried google vr sdk but it is not working. i dont know what i am doing wrong. and i found that we can't use google vr sdk libraries as dependency in build.gradle. so please give me any alternative way to make a 360 degree video player. or please tell me about google vr sdk step by step. so that i can make the app.

Thankyou in advance

i am trying to import and download the google vr sdk. but it is not working. and in console it is saying "Failed to resolve: ".

i also manually tried it.

1. i visit this link: https://developers.google.com/vr/develop/android/get-started
2. then i goto https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/releases and downloaded the latest version.
3. then imported the sdk-base-1.200.0.aar from libraries folder of extracted file.
4. i imported it in libs folder of my project.
5. then i enter the dependancy in build.gradle.
6. when i try to use it in activity layout it is only showing:

[image]

but i have to use VrVideoView . please tell me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is late but maybe someone will find this helpful.

Add this into your gradle.

`implementation "com.google.vr:sdk-videowidget:1.180.0"`